# How to make a ''Follow Curve'' animation more harmonious?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

i made a camera follow a curve with the option Ctrl + P (Follow Curve) and it works good except for the fact that when the camera reach a vertice (curve) it turns too abrupt, is there any way to fix this? i tried with the graph editor...but i see no keyframes...
Help! :(

[image]

Comment: Use the curve only for position and control the camera rotation separately (keyframes, track_to with influence, ..)

Comment: Or put a softbody rig between the curve and camera as a damper and simulate it (works like a steadycam)

Comment: You can increase the curve resolution in the properties data tab (Resolution - Preview U). Could you upload an image? Not sure if that is your problem.

Comment: I uploaded a picture there

Comment: Use constraints instead of "Follow path". Then you can animate the rotation of the camera at the frames you want =)

Comment: This will help with your animation: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23854/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Undo the parenting that you did with CTRL + P. It's handy, but it's limited.

Then select the camera and go to constraints. Select constrain "Follow path".
[image]

Then choose the curve as target, in the constraints menu.
[image]

Now you can select the curve and go to the "data" tab(the one that looks like a curve).
Under "Path animation" you can animate how fast and far the camera will move on the curve.

[image]

If you select the camera, you can animate the rotation as a normal animation(You can reset the position of the camera with "alt + g" to snap it to the curve).

Comment: Here i also uploaded a video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/as751siajpqetsc/clip0003.avi?dl=0

Comment: I see. Try the solution that I've posted - it should solve your problem.

But don't use the "Follow" option under "Path animation". You want to animate the cameras rotation manually.

Comment: "Follow path" when you parent(CTRL + P) forces the camera to rotate along with the path. The abrupt rotations you are experiencing will always be present in abrupt turns. Unless you animate the rotation manually, like I've suggested =)

Comment: Sorry, i wasnt able to answer before, the Follow Path option doesn't work, the camera doesnt follow the path or animates (it just doesn't start)

Comment: Don't use the "Follow" option(let it be unchecked). Do the steps I've suggested. Then go to "Path animation" (3'rd picture). Keyframe the "Evaluation time". Let's say you keyframe the evaluation time at 0 on frame 10 and 100 on frame 70. The camera will now follow the entire path, starting at frame 10 and ending at frame 70.

Comment: After that you keyframe the rotation of the camera. This is done by selecting the camera, not the path, and animating normally.