# How to change camera movement speed on Path during animation

Tags: animation, camera, path

Im making a animation in blender that requires the camera to change speeds while moving along a path. I'm using the Curve/Path for the path. I need the camera to move at a certain speed going between 2 places, and then slow down while moving around something its focusing on.

Comment: Also make sure to set up the interpolation in the F-curve panel [![graph editor](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vXiop.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vXiop.png)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23844/what-is-the-best-way-to-animate-the-camera-path/23846#23846

Comment: Rather than using a `Follow path` constraint for the camera, and animate the `Evaluation time` value (which I found quite difficult), I fell back to animating the camera `LocRot` keys directly, this was easier for trying camera viewpoints and movements. I know that's a bypass which can cause problems if the animation is changed, but not more than animating the evaluation time I think.

Comment: You can use F-curve to define, how transformation values will change in time.

Answer (score 10):

**Make Sure you create Keyframes for the Offset value in the Follow Path Constraint.**

---

- Insert Keyframes on the [Follow Path Constraint].  Use [Fixed Position] TRUE.  The image belows shows two keyframes in the timeline and the dopesheet.

[image]

- By using keyframes to directly and easily change position, you will change the speed, usefully and indirectly.  The object can also stop moving by using the same value of keyframe at two different frames. You can also reverse direction. You will be specifying the positions (0 = start, .5 = mid, 1.0 end) along the curve.  There is no direct settings for distance per frame and this is not a large problem under many scenarios.
- There are also many tutorials at video sites that will visually explain this.  Consider searching Blender Tutorial Follow Path Constraint.

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is selecting the path and in the curve option insert your key frames on frames value

[image: Path animation]