# How to do a bezier interpolation mode animation along a path?

Tags: animation, path

When I parent an object to follow a path and animate it, I only get a linear mode animation and changing that in Grapth Editor to bezier doesn't work! How to do that?

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31578/how-to-change-camera-movement-speed-on-path-during-animation. There actually *is* another way with adding several *Envelope* F-Modifiers in the `N` panel of Graph Editor. But it's very hard to setup, especially when there're a lot of points

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you parent an object to a curve with *Follow Path* to control its motion,

[image]

In the curve editor you'll be presented with a straight line for the evaluation time with no keyframes or any way to control the interpolation. To fix that press <kbd>N</kbd> to access the properties for the curve, look for the modifiers section and erase the generator for the curve.

[image]

Now you can manually animate the motion of the object by animating the evaluation time on the curve using keyframes, those keyframes will default to bezier interpolation.

[image]