# Cam slowing down at end of path

Tags: animation, camera

I want a cam to zoom out and stop. but it looks silly when it goes from moving to full stop in a frame, so I need it to slow down a few frames before the end.

I found a  few guides, where I should edit the speed in the graph editor window but mine looks nothing like the ones others show.

mine:

[image]

why is it not the same ?

Comment: Go to key --> interpolation mode (T) --> bezier (in the graph editor)

Comment: I can't select bezier. its greyed out

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35607/1853

Comment: Just tried that. When I delete the modifier The cam does not follow the path.

Im all new to this, so is it because I have to do parent then in another way ?

Comment: Did you animate the evaluation time in the path?

Comment: no. Just added the path stuck the cam to it and thats it.