# How can I slow down my animation periodically?

Tags: animation

I have a camera parented to a path (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, follow path) and I want to edit the speed, but since there aren't any keyframes I can't use the dope sheet. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of one (or all) of these http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23835/how-can-i-edit-a-follow-path-constraint-with-the-graph-editor/23840#23840 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21041/change-start-time-of-camera-following-a-path/21046#21046 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35597/how-to-do-a-bezier-interpolation-mode-animation-along-a-path/35607#35607 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23311/cyclic-orbit-animation/23328#23328