# Where do I edit the the keyframes of a bezier curve path animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

I made the camera move on a bezier circle path using the following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63_nvGRHLIQ&t=184s).

I would like to make the motion of the camera to be slow in the beginning and the end of the timeline, however, I couldn't find the the keyframes in the dope sheet. I also want to edit the motion curves in the graph editor, I couldn't do this as well. Any idea where can I find those modifications?

In the outliner, it shows that there is some keyframes for editing, I just couldn't find where to do it.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35597/how-to-do-a-bezier-interpolation-mode-animation-along-a-path/35607#35607 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21041/change-start-time-of-camera-following-a-path/21046#21046

Comment: did you really mean the node editor? because you will not find anything for your animation in there.

Comment: I meant the dope sheet, I corrected it, thank you for bringing this to my attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you could not find the keyframes is because there aren't any!
See when you use the *Follow Path* command blender sets up the curve animation by using a generator. You can see this generator by opening up the properties panel in the graph editor, with the curve selected.
[image: animation modifiers in the graph editor]

That is not what you want. You need just two regular keyframes. So delete that modifier (just click the X).
Now you can keyframe the curve *Evaluation Time*. Go to the first frame, set the Evaluation Time to 0 hover over the input field, and press <kbd>`I`</kbd>
Now go to frame 100 and set the evaluation time to 100, again hover over the input field, and press <kbd>`I`</kbd>.
[image: Evaluation Time setting]

Now in the graph editor you will see your animation (if the curve is still selected). You can drag out the ending keyframe to make the whole animation last longer (camera spin slower), but what you are really interested in is changing the curve. (By default the interpolation type is *Bezier* and that is what you want.)

With the generator you were getting a linear animation, with the bezier interpolated keyframes you have a nice easing at either end.