# How can I make an object hold a position while following a path?

Tags: path

I have my camera following a path.
But this path is used by other objects, and these objects need to complete the entire path. But not the camera: I want the camera to stay fixed at one moment.
So, my idea was to set the influence of the follow path constraint, for the camera, to 0, at the frame I want the camera to not follow th path anymore.
But the problem is that, at this time, the camera goes back to its origin position.

So how to hold the position of the camera when breaking the following path constraint?
I tried by inserting a locrotscale keyframe at the frame just before having put the influence to 0; but it still goes back to the origin.

Thank you

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23844/what-is-the-best-way-to-animate-the-camera-path/23846#23846

Comment: Also related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31578/how-to-change-camera-movement-speed-on-path-during-animation

Comment: Ok but what I understand by reading this is for adjusting speed while following the path. My problem is a little bit different. I dont want to complete the whole path. I want to stop at a specific location and to keep this location. In fact my character makes the whole path and my camera follows the character thanks to the path. At one moment I whant my camera to do something else while my character keeps following the path.

Comment: If you don't want the camera to move all along the path, you simply insert 2 keyframes for **Offset** option of the **Follow Path** constraint  with identical values - the camera will not move as long as these value are the same. This is told [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31583/1245) and in more details [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23846/1245)

Comment: you should check the "fixed position" on the follow path constraint , and animate the "offset" value this way you have total command on the camera position along the path