# Is there a way to interpolate animations with arcs?

Tags: animation, keyframes

Whenever you animate with key frames, even though the speed can vary, it's always only a straight line, so the end result usually looks jagged in some way. Is there a way to make an animation keyframe from point A to point B make the shape of some kind of subtle arc rather than just a straight line?

Comment: This is what you need: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31578/how-to-change-camera-movement-speed-on-path-during-animation/31583?s=5|34.2740#31583

Comment: Path Constraint  ....

Answer (score 1):

Use the Graph Editor to edit the animation curves. This will allow you to have full control over the shape of the animation. In the graph editor you can select a specific channel (such as the Z Location) and can then add keyframes by way of the Key/Insert Keyframe menu (or <kbd>I</kbd> shortcut) and these can be manipulated by grabbing and rotating the bezier handles (assuming it's set to Bezier - the default interpolation mode).

[image: graph editor]

Once you've adjusted the curve it is useful to use the Motion Paths panel to visualise the new path (as in LeoNas's answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have play with **Motion paths**

Click the butom **calculate**. It will generate the path.

Position a new keyframe in between two keyframes, and **update paths.

So you will create a curved path instead a straight line animation.

See the imagem below.

[image]

Comment: How does this work for rotating bones?

Comment: I think it is useful for IK bones or any unconnected bones as the main bone. You cannot make an arc with a connected bone because its pivot