# How to smooth camera animation to have fluid feel?

Tags: animation, camera, soft-body

When dealing with camera motion, its very sensitive to any movement discontinuities. Is there a way to easily achieve natural looking motion when dealing with complicated motion paths and timings?

Follow path animation feels too robotic unless I adjust all the keyframe easings carefully and this has to be re-done everytime the animation changes (the automatic bezier type just doesn't work).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A way to achieve camera motion with fluid non-synthetic feel is with **softbody camera rig**. This will do **automatic easing** of any motion and will save some graph-editor work.

1. Create a filled Circle with 3 vertices, subdivide it and delete the middle face:

   [image]
2. Create new empty vertex group, don't assign any vertices to it, leave it empty:

   [image]
3. Add camera to the scene and parent it to the 3 inner vertices (select *Camera*, select *Mesh*, enter edit-mode, select vertices, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>):

   [image]
4. Add *Soft Body* to the mesh object. These are the settings to take care of:

   - Friction: higher will be more lazy smoother camera
   - Damping: less means more camera jiggle and more overshoot

   [image]
5. Its good to hide the *Soft Body* modifier visibility when animating. Always bake the softbody cache. This is a result of a simple linear-interpolation animation with just 2 keyframes, you can see how the soft body smooths everything:

   [image]
6. Best it's in combination with **follow path** animation to smooth any paths and timing discontinuities. Use the *Follow Path* constraint on the softbody to animate the location (animate evaluation time under the curve) and *Track To* constraint or just keyframes for the softbody rotation.

   [image]
7. **The resulting camera motion will be the curve smoothed, so even when the curve itself is not C2 smooth the resulting animation will be.** This can't be done in graph editor or with smoothing the curve with smooth modifier (it follows the un-smoothed curve)

Comment: This is an awesome solution cheers to that!

Comment: Found it - the soft body menu is under the Physics tab of the Property editor, which is on the far right.

Comment: @Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny
Why do you have to parent the camera to a mesh object? Is it not possible to add the soft body modifier to the camera itself? Just curious.

Comment: @faybn no, a camera object is basically just an empty. You can add a force-field or a rigid-body constraint to it, that's all.