# Armature: Alternate Bone Parent between 2 bones

Tags: animation, armature, bones, parent

I'm working on weapon reload animations. The magazine bone is a Child of the rest of the gun (I'm using the bone constraint "Child of" in Pose Mode). When the hand removes the magazine from the shaft the magazine should be parented to the hand. How do I switch the Parent bone in the middle of the animation?

Sofar I had to frame-by-frame move the mag with the hand and of course it's never pixel accurate. I have to do like 30 reload animations so I would be glad if somebody could help.

Comment: This is what the problem looks like https://youtu.be/iMpLyJbTgt0 The mag doesn't stick to the hand. Fixing it takes a lot of time everytime you adjust the animation.

Comment: You do that exactly like here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86451/7777, but watch for double parent transforms inside an armature.

Comment: I'll try that right now. Are you sure this will translate properly when I export it to Unity?