# Animating a plane in the graph editor with local transform orientation

Tags: animation, graph-editor, transform-orientation

I want to animate a plane using the graph editor.
Its rotated on the Z aixs a little, but in the 3d view i can use the local transform orientation to make it go foward even if its rotated.

[image]

So I made some keyframes and the plane moved on its y axis as intended.

But when I go to the graph editor I see this

[image]

I see its global X and Y position changing but id like to edit the local Y axis...

How can i edit the local positon of an object??

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot manipulate keyframes in local transform, they are stored and displayed in global transform only.

But you can parent the plane to an *Empty* and orient the plane through it. The plane's global animation is then transformed into local space of the *Empty*. This might be useful for simple short movements, but non-usable for larger animations. With more complicated movement you could have multiple empties and a dynamic child-of constraint to influence the plane only on sections of the animation. How to setup that is covered here:

[How can I build a versatile camera rig which can both orbit around its focus and pan?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86438/how-can-i-build-a-versatile-camera-rig-which-can-both-orbit-around-its-focus-and)