# Switch child constraints

Tags: rigging, constraints

I am dribbling a soccer ball. I have set a child constraint to the ball for the left foot. Works great, Mid motion the player changes to his right foot, How do I ensure I get the same effect with the right foot? I tried adding another child constraint to the relative bone but couldn't work it out

[image]

Comment: see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86451/7777

Comment: Hey, what exactly is the problem with adding another child of?

Answer (score 0):

[blender 2.8 child of](https://youtu.be/JbATJkKHtNE)

blender 2.8 child of two child left right foot.......ok

Set two child of objects to adjust the influence value to join the left right foot.

Comment: Welcome to Blender! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.