# Object Location / apply doing funny things

Tags: geometry

I set my camera rig (created following [this Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23857/70598)) to follow a path, and it’s keeping station some distance away with a faint dotted line pointing to the position on the path where I expect it to be.

I tried doing "Apply transformation" on the rig object, and that moved the gizmo and center dot of the object to where I thought it should be, but it left all the edges in the original position.

What’s going on here?