# Uneven movement on camera following a path.

Tags: animation, camera, constraints

I render a short movie. I set the camera to the circle curve to make it fly in circle. The problem is after render, the camera is a little shaky. Can anyone help me? Thanks first.

Comment: could you upload your blendfile?

Comment: Did you you make a camera follow a curve with the Ctrl + P (Follow Curve) option  or you used the "Follow path" constraint?
Please check it out: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23675/how-to-make-a-follow-curve-animation-more-harmonious May be helpful.

Comment: Without looking at the blend file is hard to imagine what you mean by "a little shaky" please upload the blend file.

Comment: I uploaded it. You can check it now https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sa5u5wacqbum6y1/AAD3EAay8MpDKiJj8z-T0kMYa?dl=0

Comment: I Agree with @Gonzou : parenting the camera to the circle gives you very limited options to control the movement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resolution for the circle is way too low, increase the resolution for the **Active Spline**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the late respond. But it worked. Thanks, man!!!

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. But I don't have the option of changing the resolution as highlighted in the above answer. I just have two checkboxes. 'U' and 'smooth' . I'm using Blender 2.76

Comment: @Sum-Al please ask your question on a new post using the blue [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link at the top of the page and add images that show what you have.

Comment: I've asked my question here. Attached the blender file as well. Can you please look into it once
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88633/object-wobbling-and-shaking-while-camera-following-a-path